# how to use rxjava on three parallel polling events with timeout

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

There are three parallel polling events, polled every 200 milliseconds, and when one of the polls reaches the result, the three polling events stop, or stop after timeout 2s,How to achieve it using rxjava

```java
var e1 = Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(new IoScheduler())
            .map((s) -> EEventType.EVENT_1)
            .filter(s -> s != EEventType.NONE);
var e2 = Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(new IoScheduler())
            .map((s) -> EEventType.NONE)
            .filter(s -> s != EEventType.NONE);
var e3 = Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(new IoScheduler())
            .map((s) -> EEventType.NONE)
            .filter(s -> s != EEventType.NONE);

Observable.merge(e1, e2, e3)
    .timeout(2000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reaches the result"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: The three events are parallel, and  200ms intervals to get whether an event has occurred, the timeout is 2s, of course, the event does not necessarily occur, as long as one of the events occurs and is the required event, then get the event. thank you!

Comment: Forgive me for my broken English!!!

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. Does a `.first()` after your `timeout` work?